# Can't find /bundle.js.map on the server Node.js

Tags: node.js, parceljs

I am following a tutorial , now i am getting this error when i try to update a user data , i have tried to re-install parcel package

```
npm install -g bundle-js
```

here is package.json:

[image]

here is directory:

[image]

since my bundle.js and bundle.js.map is under the /public/js , how can i route the directory 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well, once bundler.js has been compiled if we open it and scroll to the very bottom, there is a line:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=/bundle.js.map
```

We can manually type the correct path like

```
//# sourceMappingURL=/js/bundle.js.map
```

the error would disappear though the question is why the parcel makes the path this way....

P.S.>

Finally, the solution is found! You should insert **--public-url .** it'll do the trick!

```
    "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js --public-url .",
    "build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js --public-url ."
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html) you can run `npm install -g parcel-bundler`.

Inside of package.json add `--out-dir .public/js` like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js",
    "build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"
  },
```

Edit: Restart both the Node.js server and the bundler for changes to work.

Answer (score 0):

**package.json**
"scripts": {
"watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js",
"build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"
},

I ran into the same issue. Here's the message I get in console:
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/bundle.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Everything seems to be working, the file's location is in .public/js for no reason the server is looking for the file in the root.