# Violation of Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, compiler-errors, content-security-policy

In my full-stack project (server-side rendered) I have my bundle.js file which I am including in my base HTML file using a simple script tag, but on trying to render the page and using the JS functionality, it gives the error of violation of content security policy

This is the error I receive

[image]

I found several solutions on Stack Overflow here : [Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)

However none of the given solutions seem to fix the issue. Please tell how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
// Download helmet
npm install helmet
```

```js
const helmet = require('helmet')

app.use(helmet());

app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      "default-src": ["'self'"],
      "connect-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
      "img-src": ["'self'", "data:"],
      "style-src-elem": ["'self'", "data:"],
      "script-src": ["'unsafe-inline'", "'self'"],
      "object-src": ["'none'"],
    },
  })
);
```

Please add some more code so I can help you more

Answer (score 0):

Guess you don't even use Content Security Policy in your project and got very surprised to get related errors.

Thing is your `bundle.js` creates websocket connection (in line 8769) and makes some XMLHttpRequest() or fetch() requests (in line 7655) to URLs which don't have a routing in the server.
For nonexistent pages (404 Not found) the `finalhandler` is performed, which publish `default-src 'self'` policy by default (by the way you use old software, the `finalhandler` after May 2019 [uses](https://uni.edu.gt/eventos/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js) `default-src 'none'` by default).

Your requests fall to 404 Not found page which haven't the content requested, and additionally all is block by CSP `default-src 'self'`.

Therefore you need to set right static routing and I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204458/cant-find-bundle-js-map-on-the-server-node-js) is your right topic.

PS: it was the fact that Express does not serve the root folder by default. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614336/why-do-i-get-the-default-src-none-content-security-policy-error-on-react-pw#comment114439530_64631888) it was solved exactly the same issue with favicon.ico locked by CSP out of blue sky.